# Place buttons outside of carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 4, I'd like to place full height buttons on the left and right sides of a carousel. The carousel should be the largest element, so something like `col-10` makes sense for its size.

Here is what I have so far:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* show 3 items */
  .carousel-inner .active,
  .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    display: block;
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    transition: none;
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -33.3333%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* left or forward direction */
  .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  /* right or prev direction */
  .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f49b41/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f4f141/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/8e41f4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
<button class="col-1">Left button goes here</button>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide col-10" data-ride="carousel">
  ...
</div>
<button class="col-1">Right button goes here</button>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just the place the carousel and button inside the bootstrap column it should work.

As sample like below format:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <button class="btn-default">Left button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <button class="btn-default">Right button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* show 3 items */
    .carousel-inner .active,
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        display: block;
    }
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        transition: none;
    }
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -33.3333%;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* left or forward direction */
    .active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    /* right or prev direction */
    .active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
    .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <button class="btn-default">Left button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto">
                    <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f44242/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Card 1</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/418cf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Card 2</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/3ed846/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Card 3</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/42ebf4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Card 4</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f49b41/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Card 5</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/f4f141/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Card 6</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x600/8e41f4/fff" alt="Card image cap">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">Card 7</h4>
                                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <button class="btn-default">Right button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```